# Placeholder overlays username and password which are remember in browser

Tags: autocomplete, autofill

I created input form for floating placeholder to top of input text feild when I have onChange in input. But I have username and password which are remember in browser (chrome) then when I refresh page placeholder will overlay username and password because username and password that was remembered it hasn't onChange. And if I click anywhere in that page placeholder will float to top [placeholder overlays text image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmzSN.png)

How to solve this problem?